# Unable to listen to incoming data from Realtime Database (RTDB) in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the structure of my realtime database.

[image]

In Flutter (ios) I try creating a reference with the code below:

```dart
final tempRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("temp_hum");
```

Then I follow the common protocol to listen for changes in the database with the code below and I can't event get the print statement in _onIncomingEvent to work

```dart
class _TemperatureProgressState extends State<TemperatureProgress> {
  List<Temperature> tempList;
  StreamSubscription<Event> _onTempSubscription;

 _onIncomingTemp(Event event) {
    print('event: ' +  event.snapshot.toString());
 }
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tempList = new List();
    _onTempSubscription = tempRef.onChildAdded.listen(_onIncomingTemp);
    print('sup');
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I am thinking one of the following is the error:
 - that my code might be wrong
 - I am not creating my firebase reference properly with child('temp_hum')
 - I might not even be connected to the right database?

UPDATE 1:
 - I found out that I was pointing to the wrong database URL in my `GoogleService-Info.splist` file. Still unable to get incoming data though

UPDATE 2: 
 - I'm now able to get data by listening from `.then()`. However, I only get the data once, is there a way to keep on listening?

```dart
tempRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
   print('data: ${snapshot.value}');
});
```

Comment: As its name implies `once` only fires once. To get realtime updates, you need `.onValue.listen(...`

Comment: it took me a while to find that but that's what exactly what I needed! I will be updating my code above

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. You might want to post it as an *answer* instead of as an edit to your question. Self-answering questions is accepted and even appreciated on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Will do thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, code will be below. As Frank in the comment says, once() will only make a query once, so it will work for retrieving data from a get request. My requirement was to continuously listen to data. Just an extra piece of info, `limitToLast(1)` will receive the most recent piece of data instead of receiving everything from whatever collection you're "listening" to from Firebase's Realtime Database.

```dart
    tempRef.limitToLast(1).onValue.listen((Event event) {
       Map data = event.snapshot.value;
          data.forEach((index, data) => {
             print('weight data: ${data}'),
             setState((){
               weightList.add(new Weight(data['avg_weight'], data['hive_weight'], data['object_id'], data['time'], data['user_id']));
          })
       });
    });
```